# Windows Camera Resolution Control in C#

Tags: c#, windows, mobile, camera

```
var maxResolution = captureManager.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo).Aggregate((i1, i2) => (i1 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width > (i2 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width ? i1 : i2);
await captureManager.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo, maxResolution);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i am using this script in my application for windows mobile camera, but my resolution and dimensions are not matching with the Nokia Lumia pictures. Can you suggest me to take control over the resolution of camera in my application.